# ngform checkbox selection array submission

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have used a step wizard utilising ngform. After the a user clicks "next" and that saves locally the users selection until the form submits on the final step.

I have introduced checkboxes to step 1 of the form. I can build up an array of the new chosen checkboxes and I also get an array for he rest of the form. I have tried combining the two but my form model does not like it.

Here is a stackblitz of my efforts so far - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7cu3x

**main Issue** - you will notice in the stackblitz above that after step 1 is complete and the checkboxes have been selected the selection array remains empty.

**html - checkbox**

```
<div *ngFor="let selection of intelSelections; let i=index">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    {{selection}}
  </label>
  <input class="form-check-input" [ngModel]="isSelected(selection)" (ngModelChange)="onChange(selection, $event)" type="checkbox" name="intelgroup_{{i}}">
</div>
```

**component.ts - checkbox logic**

```
isSelected(value: string): boolean {
    return this.selectedIntel.indexOf(value) >= 0;
}

onChange(value: string, checked: boolean) {
    console.log(value, checked);
    if (checked) {
        this.selectedIntel.push(value);
    } else {
        let index = this.selectedIntel.indexOf(value);
        this.selectedIntel.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

**SAVE step 1**

```
save(form: any): boolean {
    this.formDataService.setPersonal(this.personal);
    return true;
}
```

`this.personal` is the other array of input data on the form that gets submitted.

I can see two options:

1. combine `this.selectedIntel` to `this.personal`
2. `[ngModel]="isSelected(selection)"` figure out how to add personal.selection to ngModel.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem seems to be...why don't you just do `this.personal.selection = this.selectedIntel;` in your save method?

Comment: can you add this as an answer? thanks, thats all i needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your save method to:

```
save(form: any): boolean {
    this.personal.selection = this.selectedIntel;
    this.formDataService.setPersonal(this.personal);
    return true;
}
```